# How to reimport gpg key replaced by stub

Tags: gnupg, smartcard

I've got a subkey which was moved to a card. This resulted in replacing it with a stub in the local keychain. This means every time I try to use that subkey, I get:

```
gpg: public key decryption failed: Card error
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

I'd like to restore the key from a backup now. How can I do that?

I've tried `gpg --edit-key ...` and then `key n, toggle, delkey`, but when I tried to import the key again, I still get the secret key unchanged:

```
gpg: Total number processed: 3
gpg:            new subkeys: 1
gpg:         new signatures: 1
gpg:       secret keys read: 3
gpg:  secret keys unchanged: 1
```

How can I replace my local stub?

Answer (score 4):

This is a known problem with GnuPG up to version 2.0. You cannot import secret keys, if you already have some imported.

How to resolve the issue depends on your situation. *Backups required for all of the solutions!*

- **You're already using GnuPG 2.1.**

  You're very lucky, as the problem does not exist at all. Well, not. Obviously you're not yet using GnuPG 2.1, otherwise you wouldn't have stumbled over that problem. But you might be able to upgrade.

  You could even use it on sime live CD, import everything (automatically merging the secret keys), and finally exporting the merged key. Now drop the key on your normal system and reimport it.
- **You haven't added any subkeys, so your backup includes all of them.**

  You're lucky. Simply export all your certifications, ... using `gpg --export [key-id] > public-key.pgp`. Now completely delete the key using `gpg --delete-secret-and-public-keys [key-id]`, import your backup *followed by*  the public key: `gpg --import [backup-file] public-key.pgp`.
- **You changed your subkeys, so you have to merge them.**

  Bad luck. GnuPG will not handle this on its own. Two choices left:

  - Revoke the modified keys and create new ones afterwards. This is the easy way...
  - There is a command line tool called `gpgsplit`, which will split your exported GnuPG keys into the individual packets. If you have those, you can put those together including all subkeys using `cat`. Be aware of using the right order of packets and not excluding something actually required!

    Though this is possible, it's definitely the hard way and will possibly require reading up a little bit in the OpenPGP specification to get an understanding of the different packets and what they do.

Comment: I've got problems with this solution unfortunately :( Regarding the version, this problem happens on gnupg 2.1.2 in my case. Regarding the backup - yes, I've got all the keys, but issuing `gpg --delete-secret-and-public-keys ...` results in `gpg: deleting secret subkey failed: Not possible with a card based key` - which is exactly the reason I wanted it deleted.

Comment: This surprises me. Having a look at [a recent GnuPG mailing list post](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2014-December/051790.html) it seems there is a bug involved. As GnuPG 2.1 merges the private and public key rings and makes them rather incompatible with older versions, I fear the only wait out of this is the sledge hammer approach: export everything (including trust), delete the key ring files, import everything again (with secret keys from the backup).